# How do I make a scoreboard score increase by a percentage? (Minecraft 1.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a map where if you buy something, the price increases by 15%, so a way to do that would be

```
/scoreboard players operation @p score1 *= @p score2
```

where score1 would be something like 15, and score2 would be 1.15% to increase score1. This would allow for almost infinite times, but scoreboards can not do decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an objective with some fake players to keep track of numbers:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Numbers dummy
/scoreboard players set 115 Numbers 115
/scoreboard players set 100 Numbers 100
```

Then, whenever you want to increase it by 15%, multiply the player's score by 115, then divide it by 100:

```
/scoreboard players operation @p score1 *= 115 Numbers
/scoreboard players operation @p score1 /= 100 Numbers
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, and I never thought of doing it like that. :P

Comment: @user155735 No problem. Press the tick on the left if the answer worked for you to confirm it.

Comment: Ok, I'm new on here if you can't tell by my username not being updated for some reason, but oh well. Thanks anyway!